# Static variable for workbook filename

Tags: vba, excel

I want to declare a variable for the entire procedure - I want to name a workbook ("Dataworkbook") to use throughout all of my modules.
I tried declaring as public and still am getting the error "variable not defined"

```
Static Dataworkbook As Workbook

Set Dataworkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Sara\Data")
```

Comment: I think you want Public Dataworkbook As Workbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use public to declare as global "Static" variable

```
Option Explicit
Public Dataworkbook As Workbook

Sub Test

Set Dataworkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Sara\Data.xlsx")

End Sub
```

But make sure to include the appropriate file extension e.g. `.xlsx` when assigning the value.